# Programatically set read-only for QTimeEdit

Tags: c++, qt

QTimeEdit has a read-only property, which I can set from Designer (it is in the QAbstractSpinBox properties category).

But there is no setReadOnly member in QTimeEdit.

Comment: Yes there _is_ `setReadOnly(bool)` there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call setReadOnly. It is a member of QAbstractSpinBox, which QTimeEdit inherits from.

When looking up documentation for a particular class, don't forget to click the link "List of all members, including inherited members", which will display all of the methods you can call for a given object.

Comment: Also if one thinks he knows the method name it's faster to check it from the auto-completion list that to search in the docs :P

Comment: Yeah totally... But sometimes in Qt Creator auto completion doesn't work, particularly with containers.

Comment: I was using the auto-completion but it didn't show setReadOnly. That's why I thought there is no such method. Now it shows, but I'm on a different machine and started a new project.

Comment: OK, I was, dumb, I had been trying the autocompletion on the wrong variable, a QTime variable, instead of the QTimeEdit. And I went to the help by pressing F1 over the variable, so it took me to QTime help where I didn't find setReadOnly. Mystery solved, I guess.